# Как при нажатии на кнопку запускать анимацию, сделанную при помощи @keyframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Как при нажатии на кнопку `<button>` запускать анимацию, сделанную при помощи `@keyframes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function clickMe() {
  document.querySelector(".block").classList.toggle("block-spin");
}
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes infinite-spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.block-spin {
  animation: infinite-spinning 3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="clickMe()">Click</button>
```